# Get Time Machine's current state in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, time-machine

I'm wondering if there's any way to get the current status of Time Machine's backup process in terminal. I'm interested in whether backup is in progress (or not) and what its percentage of completion is.

Also, a time table of future backups would be useful.

Comment: There is `tmutil` but it doesn't seem to offer status information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command:

```
syslog -F '$Time $Message' -k Sender /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd -k Time ge -30m
```

This should show you any log messages generated by Time Machine in the last thirty minutes.